# Could not resolve type id 'org.redisson.codec.SmileJacksonCodec' as a subtype of `org.redisson.client.codec.Codec`: no such class found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jetty, redisson

**No Such class found** error where class already exist at class path. Initially looking at error it looks like as if class does not exist but actually class are available as can be seen in below screenshots.

org.redisson.client.codec.Codec is interface and org.redisson.codec.SmileJacksonCodec is nth level inherited class.

I am de-serializing redis-config.yaml to Config class.

The problem I have is little weird. When I deserialize below classes using spark submit program or launch application from intellij, it works perfectly fine. However, when I run this inside docker image I get into below issue for the case below

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 08 May 2023 02:51:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 295
Server: Jetty(9.4.50.v20221201)

Could not resolve type id 'org.redisson.codec.SmileJacksonCodec' as a subtype of `org.redisson.client.codec.Codec`: no such class found
 at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream); line: 20, column: 8] (through reference chain: org.redisson.config.Config["codec"])
```

Below code is bundled with spark-3.4.0 https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.4.0/spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz inside docker image and have jackson dependencies updated to 2.14.2.

Trying to build a RedisClient as follows:

```
def createRedisClient() : RedissonClient = {
      val uri = this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("redis-config.yaml")
        val config: Config = Config.fromYAML(uri)
        codec.foreach(config.setCodec)
        logger.info(s"RedisClientPool : ${config.toJSON}")
        Redisson.create(config)
}

    public class Config {
        private SentinelServersConfig sentinelServersConfig;
        private MasterSlaveServersConfig masterSlaveServersConfig;
        private SingleServerConfig singleServerConfig;
        private ClusterServersConfig clusterServersConfig;
        private ElasticacheServersConfig elasticacheServersConfig;
        private ReplicatedServersConfig replicatedServersConfig;
        private ConnectionManager connectionManager;
        private int threads = 0;
        private int nettyThreads = 0;
        private Codec codec;
        private ReferenceCodecProvider referenceCodecProvider = new DefaultReferenceCodecProvider();
        private ExecutorService executor;
        private boolean referenceEnabled = true;
        private TransportMode transportMode;
        private EventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup;
        private long lockWatchdogTimeout;
        private boolean keepPubSubOrder;
        private boolean useScriptCache;
        private AddressResolverGroupFactory addressResolverGroupFactory;
}
```

redis-config.yaml looks like

```
---
singleServerConfig:
  idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
  connectTimeout: 30000
  timeout: 30000
  retryAttempts: 3
  retryInterval: 1500
  password: null
  subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
  clientName: null
  address: "redis://redis:6379"
  subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
  subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 5
  connectionMinimumIdleSize: 8
  connectionPoolSize: 8
  database: 1
  dnsMonitoringInterval: 5000
threads: 2
nettyThreads: 4
codec: !<org.redisson.codec.SmileJacksonCodec> {}
transportMode: "NIO"
```

Above code is getting executed on a http endpoint for which server is started using following code

```
import org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server
import org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.{ServletContextHandler, ServletHolder}
    def startServer() {
          val context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS)
          context.setContextPath("/")
    
          val jettyServer = new Server(SERVER_PORT)
          jettyServer.setHandler(context)
    
          val rc = new ResourceConfig()
          rc.register(this, classOf[RestBasedMockedTopologyService])
          rc.register(classOf[JacksonFeature])
    
          val sc = new ServletContainer(rc)
          val holder = new ServletHolder(sc)
          context.addServlet(holder, "/*")
    
          jettyServer.start()
       }
```

Both org.redisson.codec.SmileJacksonCodec and org.redisson.client.codec.Codec are available on class path

[image]

[image]
Request is being called from a jetty server and with this failure it turns into a bad request and throws 400 http.

Any lead please suggest.

I have also verified that verbose logs shows below for both classes

```
[Loaded org.redisson.client.codec.Codec from file:/opt/mycomosi/jars/topology-cache-management.jar]
[Loaded org.redisson.codec.SmileJacksonCodec from file:/opt/mycomosi/jars/topology-cache-management.jar]
```

When I checked using below code I get following error

```
val codecClass = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.loadClass("org.redisson.client.codec.Codec")
val smileCodecClass = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader.loadClass("org.redisson.codec.SmileJacksonCodec")

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.redisson.client.codec.Codec
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:410)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:358)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:311)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:554)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1440)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:505)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1355)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:487)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:732)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:479)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.sparkproject.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.redisson.client.codec.Codec
```

Answer (score 0):

After again and again trying finally I found a solution for this:

I added some logs for comparing class loader used before starting jetty server and when request comes in on http endpoint, it was happening like classes were getting loaded fine before and not when http request comes in.

It seems that earlier with spark 2.2.0 same class loader used to pass automatically when running a jetty server (org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server) from code but with spark 3.4.0 this is changed.
Manually passing  same class loader to the ServletContextHandler moved me up.

Adding following lines of code while starting jetty server worked for me for this problem.

```
val oldClassLoader = Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader
context.setClassLoader(oldClassLoader)

def startServer() {
   val context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS)
  context.setContextPath("/")

  val oldClassLoader = Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader
  context.setClassLoader(oldClassLoader)

  val jettyServer = new Server(SERVER_PORT)
  jettyServer.setHandler(context)

  val rc = new ResourceConfig()
  rc.register(this, classOf[RestBasedMockedUnitTopologyQueryService])
  rc.register(classOf[JacksonFeature])

  val sc = new ServletContainer(rc)
  val holder = new ServletHolder(sc)
  context.addServlet(holder, "/*")

  jettyServer.start()
}
```